# Flatten IEnumerable<string> - SelectMany issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I am trying to pull the `UserId's` from a table but when I pull it it comes in the form of a string array containing a string array.

How do I flatten this to just get a string array? I have tried using `SelectMany(i => i.UserId)` but I get the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable< char>' to'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable< string>'

Why is this? Why does it think that the result is of type char?

```
[DataContract]
public class AdminDashboardData
{
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<string> Users { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetUserIds(IEnumerable<int> groupIds)
{
    using(GameDbContext entityContext = new GameDbContext())
    {
        return entityContext.InvestigatorGroupUsers
            .Include(i => i.InvestigatorGroup)
            .Where(i => i.InvestigatorGroup.IsTrashed == false)
            .Where(i => groupIds.Contains(i.InvestigatorGroupId))
            .Select(i => i.UserId).Distinct().ToFullyLoaded();
    }
}

public class InvestigatorGroupUser
{
    public int InvestigatorGroupUserId { get; set; }
    public int InvestigatorGroupId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public InvestigatorGroup InvestigatorGroup { get; set; }
}

public AdminDashboardData GetDashboardData(string userId)
{
    IGamePlayedRepository GamePlayedRepo = _GamePlayedRepo ?? new GamePlayedRepository();

    // Get the investigator groups from the userid
    IEnumerable<int> groupIds = GroupUserRepo.GetGroupIds(userId);

    AdminDashboardData data = new AdminDashboardData();

    if (!groupIds.IsNullOrEmpty())
    {
        data.Users = GroupUserRepo.GetUserIds(groupIds);
    }

    return data;
}

public static IEnumerable<T> ToFullyLoaded<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    return enumerable.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Your `UserID` is a `string`, not a string array. It can be enumerated in order to get its characters of type `char`. This explains the exception. SelectMany is not required.

Comment: What does the method `ToFullyLoaded()` do?

Comment: The way your code is written it should be returning a string array because UserId is a string, not an array of strings.  I'm guessing using selectmany is selecting character arrays of your strings and flattening them into a character array.

Comment: You are doing `SelectMany(i => i.UserId)` on userid, where `userid` seems to be `string`, so SelectMany returns `IEnumerable<char>`. Please explain this properly *"when I pull it it comes in the form of a string array"*.

Comment: What I am trying to do is get all the `UserId's` and store it into an `IEnumerable<string>` in my data contract. `ToFullyLoaded()` is the same as `ToList()`

Comment: @ArghyaC `data.Users` is an `IEnumerable<string>` containing a `string[]`I want it to just be `IEnumerable<string>` or `string[]`

Comment: @EitanK `string[]` is an `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I thought an array is different than an `IEnumerable`. The type that is shows in my visual studio watch is `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> {string[]}`. I have to navigate down on `data.Users` and then I see `{string[5]} string[]`. I have to navigate down one more time and then I can see the elements

Comment: @EitanK Arrays are different than `IEnumerable`.  `IEnumerable` is an interface, but all arrays implement that interface, but it is not the only thing that implements that interface.  List also implements the `IEnumerable` interface as well, as does a lot of other things.

Comment: @EitanK Waht you are seeing in the debugger is that the _declared_ type of `Users` in an `IEnumerable<string>` but the _actual_ type is a `string[]`.  Similar to saying "I have an animal" when you are carrying a dog.   It is not saying that the `IEnumerable<string>` _contains_ string arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Stripping down to its essence (and substituting a database I had handy), we have this easily LinqPad-able code block:

```
void Main()
{
    GetDashboardData().Dump();
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetUserIds()
{
        return this.Peoples
            .Where(i => i.HasPhoto == false)
            .Select(i => i.FirstName).Distinct().ToFullyLoaded();
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetDashboardData()
{
    var Users = this.GetUserIds();
    return Users;
}

static class Ext
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToFullyLoaded<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        return enumerable.ToList();
    }
}
```

This displays a single dimensioned list of strings.   Whatever the problem is, it's not in this code.

Keep in mind that a string is considered a `IEnumerable<char>` so you really are getting an "array of arrays (of chars)"  but you can treat it as an array of strings.